# Also get id of input when new item is added

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I'm experimenting with jQuery tokeniputs and would like to get not only the item.name but also the id of the input when a new item gets added. There is a function variable `onAdd` that i use to invoke a alert:

```
onAdd: function (item) {
    alert("Added " + item.name);
},
```

But i really have no clue how i should get the id of the input the element gets appended to:

```
<input type="text" id="input12" name="blah" />
```

My demo code:

```
$("#input12").tokenInput("http://shell.loopj.com/tokeninput/tvshows.php", {
    prePopulate: [{
        id: 123,
        name: "Slurms MacKenzie"
    }],
    onAdd: function (item) {
        alert("Added " + item.name);
    },
    onDelete: function (item) {
        alert("Deleted " + item.name);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v394w/

Thanks!

Comment: `id` of the element,do you mean id of the `input` field

Comment: `this` in the `onAdd` method refers to the input element so you can use `this.id` to refer to the elements id

Comment: `this` refers to the jquery object, so `this.id` does not exists, if you want to do it that way use `this[0].id`

Comment: Sorry i know this belongs not to the question! But do you have any idea  how i could invoke a alert with the item.name when the user clicks on one item that yet is appended to the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the ID of the input you can do this `this.attr("id")`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#demo-input-pre-populated").tokenInput("http://shell.loopj.com/tokeninput/tvshows.php", {
        prePopulate: [{
            id: 123,
            name: "Slurms MacKenzie"
        }, {
            id: 555,
            name: "Bob Hoskins"
        }, {
            id: 9000,
            name: "Kriss Akabusi"
        }],
        onAdd: function (item) {
            console.log(this.attr("id"));
            // Input ID (this refers to the jQuery input object)
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: no reaction on JSFiddle? I mean can console.log be replaced by alert() ?